# Male vs Female society

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a short story, probably 90's or so, in which the society has been divided with males on one side, in one area, and women in the other, and the two sides are actively at war. The story focuses on the idea that reproduction must happen so when they reach that age young men and young women meet up in some neutral zone and get it on.
In the particular story when they get done the young man gets distracted and the woman kills him.

Comment: The women kill their boy children?

Comment: I feel like we've had this one before, but I have not found it yet.

Comment: Could it be the Jael's arc from The Female Man by Joanna Russ ? There are some similarities but it's not exactly the same. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Female_Man

Comment: I immediately though of Joanna Russ, but I don't think the liaisons in a neutral zone are in The Female Man.

Comment: 14111 I had the same question, but I can't remember.

Comment: John, no, this was not that one.

Comment: This one was very much one young man, one young woman, one sexual liason, one death, end of story.

Comment: I remember a story kind of like this but the woman lives in an isolated house somewhere.  If this rings a bell maybe that's it but I don't remember the name anyway just putting it out there to maybe suss up an extra detail.

Comment: No, I remember this as at a city, somehow.